# Crop Photo with Custom Shape

Tags: objective-c, swift, camera, png, crop

I'm looking for some guidance as I build out a custom camera. I've used square cropping for photos in previous projects, but now I need to create a custom crop shape. Should I do this with a path or a mask?

I need to add the cropped image to another image and generate one png image with the two images combined. Please reference photos for an idea of what I'm looking to build.

[image: Custom crop shape]

Have currently been building a bezier path, but not sure how to use the path shape to crop the image:

```
func createBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 26))

    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 12), // ending point
        controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 14),
        controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 14))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 2))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2), // center point of circle
        radius: 2, 
        startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), // π radians = 180 degrees = straight left
        endAngle: CGFloat(3*M_PI_2), // 3π/2 radians = 270 degrees = straight up
        clockwise: true) // startAngle to endAngle goes in a clockwise direction

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 0))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 2),
                radius: 2,
                startAngle: CGFloat(3*M_PI_2), // straight up
        endAngle: CGFloat(0), // 0 radians = straight right
        clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 12))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 15), // ending point
        controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 14),
        controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 14))

    path.close() 

    return path
}
```

Comment: hello @Paul k. I have to do same thing in my app(capturing only face as per above images and save) in objective c so what i have to do can you give me the link if you have any kind of library for only capture face and save so please help me..
thanks in advance

Comment: hi.sir one help my project me try to face shape image crop but not crop perfect face shape image please help me objective c..

Answer (score 2):

Put the original photo in a `UIImageView` and do:

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = createBezierPath()
imageView.layer.mask = mask
```

And it should display only the face cropped inside.
If you want to have a new `UIImage` use the `renderInContext()` method.

Comment: Thank you Alistra! I'll try this out.

Comment: hello @Alistra I have to do same thing in my app(capturing only face as per above images and save) in objective c so what i have to do can you give me the link if you have any kind of library for only capture face and save so please help me..
thanks in advance